# Drupal Webform mailing

Tags: email, drupal, twig

I got a **Drupal 10 website hosted by Hostinger**, on my locale instance I've sended some webform messages via SMTP Authentication Support plugin and it worked great, i created a custom twig template (inside webform configuration, for a custom email notification) with datas in a table, some inline style etc and my differents mails received the table, well formed. But on production website, with same configuration and a valid email, mail is sended in hard HTML. Could you help me ?

## TEMPLATE TWIG

```
<table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color: #fbe1e1; color: #201f1d; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #fbe1e1;">Client</th>
    <td style="color: #201f1d; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #fbe1e1;">[webform_submission:values:firstname:raw] [webform_submission:values:name:raw]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color: #fbe1e1; color: #201f1d; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #fbe1e1;">Email</th>
    <td style="color: #201f1d; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #fbe1e1;">[webform_submission:values:email:raw]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color: #fbe1e1; color: #201f1d; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #fbe1e1;">Téléphone</th>
    <td style="color: #201f1d; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #fbe1e1;">
      <a href="tel:[webform_submission:values:telephone:raw]" style="text-decoration: none; color: #201f1d;">[webform_submission:values:telephone:raw]</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color: #fbe1e1; color: #201f1d; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #fbe1e1;">Message</th>
    <td style="color: #201f1d; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #fbe1e1;">[webform_submission:values:message:raw]</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## WEBFORM CONFIGURATION

```
uuid: ###
langcode: fr
status: open
dependencies: {  }
weight: 0
open: null
close: null
uid: 1
template: false
archive: false
id: contact_simple
title: Contact
description: '<p>Formulaire de contact simple</p>'
category: ''
elements: |-
  name:
    '#type': textfield
    '#title': Nom
    '#required_error': 'Veuillez renseigner votre nom'
    '#multiple__no_items_message': '<p>No items entered. Please add items below.</p>'
    '#required': true
  firstname:
    '#type': textfield
    '#title': Prénom
    '#required': true
    '#required_error': 'Veuillez renseigner votre prénom'
    '#multiple__no_items_message': '<p>No items entered. Please add items below.</p>'
  telephone:
    '#type': tel
    '#title': Téléphone
    '#required': true
    '#required_error': 'Veuillez renseigner votre numéro de téléphone'
    '#multiple__no_items_message': '<p>No items entered. Please add items below.</p>'
  email:
    '#type': email
    '#title': Email
    '#required': true
    '#required_error': 'Veuillez renseigner votre email'
    '#pattern': '^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$'
    '#pattern_error': "Le champ Email n'est pas au bon format, exemple : john.doe@mail.fr"
    '#multiple__no_items_message': '<p>No items entered. Please add items below.</p>'
  message:
    '#type': textarea
    '#title': Message
    '#autocomplete': ''
    '#required': true
    '#required_error': 'Veuillez renseigner un message'
    '#multiple__no_items_message': '<p>No items entered. Please add items below.</p>'
  actions:
    '#type': webform_actions
    '#title': 'Submit button(s)'
    '#submit__label': Envoyer
    '#submit__attributes':
      class:
        - button-pastel
    '#reset__label': Réinitialiser
    '#reset__attributes':
      class:
        - button-grey
css: ''
javascript: ''
settings:
  ajax: true
  ajax_scroll_top: form
  ajax_progress_type: fullscreen
  ajax_effect: ''
  ajax_speed: null
  page: false
  page_submit_path: ''
  page_confirm_path: ''
  page_theme_name: ''
  form_title: source_entity_webform
  form_submit_once: true
  form_open_message: ''
  form_close_message: ''
  form_exception_message: ''
  form_previous_submissions: true
  form_confidential: false
  form_confidential_message: ''
  form_disable_remote_addr: true
  form_convert_anonymous: false
  form_prepopulate: false
  form_prepopulate_source_entity: false
  form_prepopulate_source_entity_required: false
  form_prepopulate_source_entity_type: ''
  form_unsaved: true
  form_disable_back: true
  form_submit_back: false
  form_disable_autocomplete: false
  form_novalidate: true
  form_disable_inline_errors: false
  form_required: false
  form_autofocus: false
  form_details_toggle: false
  form_reset: true
  form_access_denied: default
  form_access_denied_title: ''
  form_access_denied_message: ''
  form_access_denied_attributes: {  }
  form_file_limit: ''
  form_attributes: {  }
  form_method: ''
  form_action: ''
  share: false
  share_node: false
  share_theme_name: ''
  share_title: true
  share_page_body_attributes: {  }
  submission_label: 'Merci !'
  submission_exception_message: ''
  submission_locked_message: ''
  submission_log: true
  submission_excluded_elements: {  }
  submission_exclude_empty: false
  submission_exclude_empty_checkbox: false
  submission_views: {  }
  submission_views_replace: {  }
  submission_user_columns: {  }
  submission_user_duplicate: false
  submission_access_denied: default
  submission_access_denied_title: ''
  submission_access_denied_message: ''
  submission_access_denied_attributes: {  }
  previous_submission_message: ''
  previous_submissions_message: ''
  autofill: false
  autofill_message: ''
  autofill_excluded_elements: {  }
  wizard_progress_bar: false
  wizard_progress_pages: false
  wizard_progress_percentage: false
  wizard_progress_link: false
  wizard_progress_states: false
  wizard_start_label: ''
  wizard_preview_link: false
  wizard_confirmation: true
  wizard_confirmation_label: ''
  wizard_auto_forward: true
  wizard_auto_forward_hide_next_button: false
  wizard_keyboard: true
  wizard_track: ''
  wizard_prev_button_label: ''
  wizard_next_button_label: ''
  wizard_toggle: false
  wizard_toggle_show_label: ''
  wizard_toggle_hide_label: ''
  wizard_page_type: container
  wizard_page_title_tag: h2
  preview: 0
  preview_label: ''
  preview_title: ''
  preview_message: ''
  preview_attributes: {  }
  preview_excluded_elements: {  }
  preview_exclude_empty: true
  preview_exclude_empty_checkbox: false
  draft: none
  draft_multiple: false
  draft_auto_save: false
  draft_saved_message: ''
  draft_loaded_message: ''
  draft_pending_single_message: ''
  draft_pending_multiple_message: ''
  confirmation_type: message
  confirmation_url: '<front>'
  confirmation_title: 'Merci !'
  confirmation_message: '<p>Votre message a bien été envoyé, je vous recontacterais sous peu.</p>'
  confirmation_attributes: {  }
  confirmation_back: true
  confirmation_back_label: ''
  confirmation_back_attributes: {  }
  confirmation_exclude_query: false
  confirmation_exclude_token: false
  confirmation_update: false
  limit_total: null
  limit_total_interval: null
  limit_total_message: ''
  limit_total_unique: false
  limit_user: null
  limit_user_interval: null
  limit_user_message: ''
  limit_user_unique: false
  entity_limit_total: null
  entity_limit_total_interval: null
  entity_limit_user: null
  entity_limit_user_interval: null
  purge: all
  purge_days: 90
  results_disabled: false
  results_disabled_ignore: false
  results_customize: false
  token_view: false
  token_update: false
  token_delete: false
  serial_disabled: false
access:
  create:
    roles:
      - anonymous
      - authenticated
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  view_any:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  update_any:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  delete_any:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  purge_any:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  view_own:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  update_own:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  delete_own:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  administer:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  test:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
  configuration:
    roles: {  }
    users: {  }
    permissions: {  }
handlers:
  email_confirmation:
    id: email
    handler_id: email_confirmation
    label: 'Email confirmation'
    notes: ''
    status: false
    conditions: {  }
    weight: 0
    settings:
      states:
        - completed
      to_mail: '[webform_submission:values:email:raw]'
      to_options: {  }
      bcc_mail: ''
      bcc_options: {  }
      cc_mail: ''
      cc_options: {  }
      from_mail: _default
      from_options: {  }
      from_name: _default
      reply_to: ''
      return_path: ''
      sender_mail: ''
      sender_name: '[site:name]'
      subject: _default
      body: _default
      excluded_elements: {  }
      ignore_access: false
      exclude_empty: true
      exclude_empty_checkbox: false
      exclude_attachments: false
      html: true
      attachments: false
      twig: false
      theme_name: morganimo
      parameters: {  }
      debug: false
  email_notification:
    id: email
    handler_id: email_notification
    label: 'Email notification'
    notes: ''
    status: true
    conditions: {  }
    weight: 0
    settings:
      states:
        - completed
      to_mail: _default
      to_options: {  }
      bcc_mail: ''
      bcc_options: {  }
      cc_mail: ''
      cc_options: {  }
      from_mail: _default
      from_options: {  }
      from_name: '[webform_submission:values:name:raw] [webform_submission:values:firstname:raw]'
      reply_to: ''
      return_path: ''
      sender_mail: ''
      sender_name: ''
      subject: 'Formulaire de contact'
      body: '<p>&lt;table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0"&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;th style="background-color: #fbe1e1; color: #201f1d; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #fbe1e1;"&gt;Client&lt;/th&gt;&lt;td style="color: #201f1d; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #fbe1e1;"&gt;[webform_submission:values:firstname:raw] [webform_submission:values:name:raw]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;th style="background-color: #fbe1e1; color: #201f1d; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #fbe1e1;"&gt;Email&lt;/th&gt;&lt;td style="color: #201f1d; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #fbe1e1;"&gt;[webform_submission:values:email:raw]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;th style="background-color: #fbe1e1; color: #201f1d; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #fbe1e1;"&gt;Téléphone&lt;/th&gt;&lt;td style="color: #201f1d; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #fbe1e1;"&gt;&lt;a href="tel:[webform_submission:values:telephone:raw]" style="text-decoration: none; color: #201f1d;"&gt;[webform_submission:values:telephone:raw]&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;th style="background-color: #fbe1e1; color: #201f1d; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #fbe1e1;"&gt;Message&lt;/th&gt;&lt;td style="color: #201f1d; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #fbe1e1;"&gt;[webform_submission:values:message:raw]&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;</p>'
      excluded_elements: {  }
      ignore_access: false
      exclude_empty: true
      exclude_empty_checkbox: false
      exclude_attachments: false
      html: true
      attachments: false
      twig: false
      theme_name: ''
      parameters: {  }
      debug: false
variants: {  }
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: check your `handlers.email_notification.settings.body` config. It looks like it has sanitised your html and put it in a p tag

Comment: Thanks ! I did'nt noticed that, but with the same "mistake" it works great in my locale environment.